# Mongoid caching or multiple requests accessing the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nginx, mongoid, passenger

I have an application running on Rails 4 using MongoDB and mongoid to connect the Rails app with Mongodb.

Let me please paste in a few lines of my trouble maker code.

```
def generate_transaction_uuid
  current_time = Time.now
  julian_date = current_time.strftime("%j")
  year = current_time.strftime("%Y")
  date = current_time.strftime("%H")
  channel_identifier = '1' 
  last_transaction_random_sequence = TransactionUuid.last.transaction_uuid[-5..-1]

  if last_transaction_random_sequence.to_i == 99999
    running_sequence_numbers = '00000'
  else
    current_sequence_number = (last_transaction_random_sequence.to_i + 1).to_s
    running_sequence_numbers = '0' * (5 - (current_sequence_number).length) +  current_sequence_number.to_s
  end

  uuid = year[-1] + julian_date[-3..-1] + date + channel_identifier + running_sequence_numbers
  TransactionUuid.create(transaction_uuid: uuid)
  uuid
end
```

The code above generates a transaction uuid. The logic ( the core part ) is generating the last 5 digits of the transaction id, the running sequence number. Currently the logic is to generate an id and store it in a table '**TransactionUuid**'. When the next request arrives, the last stored uuid is queried from the table, the last 5 digits extracted out of that and the next sequence number is created. Its again inserted into the DB and the process goes on.

```
last_transaction_random_sequence = TransactionUuid.last.transaction_uuid[-5..-1]

if last_transaction_random_sequence.to_i == 99999
  running_sequence_numbers = '00000'
else
  current_sequence_number = (last_transaction_random_sequence.to_i + 1).to_s
  running_sequence_numbers = '0' * (5 - (current_sequence_number).length) +  current_sequence_number.to_s
end
```

This works fine in most cases and gives unique transaction ids for each Rails request. But on certain cases, this generates duplicate transaction Ids. Why exactly does that happen is quite unclear to me because from the code its quite evident that the transaction Ids generated are to be unique. Also, when i run the code manually it doesnt seem to be having a problem.

I inspected into the Rails logs to check if the problem is having two simultaneous requests accessing the database at the same time, which is possible. But from the Rails logs, it seems that even **requests that have a difference of about 20seconds** in between them seem to generate the same transaction id on certain instances. This is whats really confusing me. We use nginx-passenger to serve our requests.

What exactly might be the issue here, some kind of database caching that happens internally or some totally unrelated weird problem or may be even a bug in my code? Any kind of help on this would be much appreciated.